# ESC/POS not Printing Barcodes

Tags: linux, echo, barcode, escpos

I'm writing an app that needs to print receipts. I purchased a thermal printer that claims to accept ESC/POS commands, but I can't get it print barcodes for some reason. I'm testing it in Linux simply writing into the usb file for the printer using `echo`. I can get it to print text and accept other commands such as underline, bold, etc. Is anyone familiar enough with ESC/POS to tell me if the following command should work?

```
echo -e "\x1d\x6b\x041234\x00" > /dev/usb/lp0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this command is correct.  It should print a code39 barcode with the letters 1234.  You could try to set the barcode height using the command GS h n, e.g. \x1d\x68\x80 to set the height to 128 dots (1 <= n <= 255).

Comment: Thanks for verifying that for me! It looks like this particular printer just doesn't accept barcode commands, which is frustrating. Thanks again!

Comment: What kind of printer is that (brand, model)?

Comment: AGPtEK SC35-5890F. I emailed the company and they confirmed it won't accept barcode commands despite advertising it was ESC/POS compliant.

Comment: Looks like bad luck, then.  If the printer at least supports the bitmap printing commands, you could create an image of the barcode in memory and send that to the printer, but maybe that's not worth the effort.  Pbly better to get a different printer.